# rabbitpy message loop seems to consume massive memory

Tags: python, rabbitpy

Using the standard procedure (for loop) as seen in the examples we found that there is a lot of memory used on the machine. I.e. it seems that all the messages in the queue are loaded into memory and also acknowledged. This approach is [here](https://rabbitpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/consumer.html). I assumed the queue would be a generator.

```
import rabbitpy

with rabbitpy.Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f') as conn:
    with conn.channel() as channel:
        queue = rabbitpy.Queue(channel, 'example')

        # Exit on CTRL-C
        try:
            # Consume the message
            for message in queue:
                message.pprint(True)
                message.ack()

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print 'Exited consumer'
```

Now if we go to the message [getter](https://rabbitpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/getter.html), using one message at a time via `.get()`, it appears to be less memory hungry. However my code (using an infinite loop) to ensure our consumer has be run when there are no messages in the queue - works better, however in the web control panel, there seems to be no consumer displayed, i.e. somehow this process is not recognized as a consumer - how can we fix this, so that on the web panel we detect a consumer?

```
queue_read = rabbitpy.Queue(channel, QUEUE_NAME)
while True: 
        body = queue_read.get() ## pop one at a time.
        if body == None:
                time.sleep(3)               
                continue
        body.ack()
        print " [x]  OK - got a message"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you need is to set the `prefetch` property when consuming the queue. Instead of:

```
for message in queue:
    # handle message
```

Try instead:

```
for message in queue.consume(prefetch=5): # or some other reasonable value
    # handle message
```

The `__iter__` method on the `Queue` class is just a simple call to the `consume` method itself.

The `consume` method sets the `channel` to a `consuming` state, while the `get` method merely pulls a message out of the `channel` and has no idea if you are going to continue consuming in the future. Which is why you aren' t seeing your process in the web panel.

Comment: I haven't used the library, merely read the source code and came to this conclusion. I'd test and make sure it fits your needs.